# SwiftUI ForEach with .indices() does not update after onDelete

Tags: swiftui, indices

my problem is: I have simple array with some Items. I want to display a `List` with these items using a `ForEach` with `.indices()`.
(This is because my actual problem handles with `Toggle` in a `List` and for the `isOn` binding I need the index to address a model that is bound to an `EnvironmentObject`). So the solution to loop over the array `items` is no possible solution for my problem.

The simplified starting point looks like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items.indices) {index in
                Text(self.items[index])
            }.onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
        }
    }
    
    func deleteItem(indexSet: IndexSet) {
        self.items.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }
}
```

If I now try to swipe-delete a row, I get this error message:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

Debugging the `index` value inside the closure, I can see, that the indices of the `items`-array does not update. For example: If I delete the first row with `"Item 1"` and inspect the value of `index` after deleting the row it returns `2` instead of `0` (which is the expected first index of the array). Why is this and how can I fix this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use dynamic content `ForEach` constructor `(_ data: .., id: ...)`

```
ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) {index in   // << here !!
    Text(self.items[index])
}.onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Asperi. It works well. Now I tried your solution with a ```Model```-class that has an array of ```[Item]```. And ```Item``` is a struct that conforms to ```Identifiable``` and has a Boolean-attribute. Now if I build the same View like above everything is fine. But when I replace the ```Text()```-View with a ```Toggle()``` which is controlled by the Boolean-Value, I get another error on delete (this time inside the ```AppDelegate```): ```Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range```. What happens here?

Comment: This fixed my issue...... With the traditional approach, in the first viewLoad my array has 3 elements, and 3 items are displayed......   In the reload, the array has one item, but the ForEach ran through indices 0, 1, 2.    Even though I cold inspect items.count and it was = 1, right before the ForEach....   Weird.....