# SwiftUI onDelete List with Toggle and NavigationLink

Tags: list, binding, swiftui, toggle, swiftui-navigationlink

I refer to two questions that I already asked and have been answered very well by Asperi: [SwiftUI ForEach with .indices() does not update after onDelete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62909572/swiftui-foreach-with-indices-does-not-update-after-ondelete),
[SwiftUI onDelete List with Toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62948754/swiftui-ondelete-list-with-toggle)

Now I tried to modify the closure in `ForEach` with a `NavigationLink` and suddenly the App crashes again with

`Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`

when I try to swipe-delete.

Code:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var items: [Item]
    
    init(name: String, items: [Item]) {
        self.name = name
        self.items = items
    }   
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var isOn: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(model.items) {item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: self.makeBinding(id: item.id))) {
                        Toggle(isOn: self.makeBinding(id: item.id).isOn)
                        {Text("Toggle-Text")}
                    }
                }.onDelete(perform: delete)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        self.model.items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
    
    func makeBinding(id: UUID) -> Binding<Item> {
        guard let index = self.model.items.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == id}) else {
            fatalError("This person does not exist")
        }
        return Binding(get: {self.model.items[index]}, set: {self.model.items[index] = $0})
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $item.isOn) {
            Text("Toggle-Text")
        }
    }
}
```

It works without `NavigationLink` OR without the `Toggle`. So it seems for me that I only can use the `makeBinding`-Function once in this closure.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Your code was crashing for me with and even without Navigation Link. Sometimes only if I deleted the last object in the Array. It looks like it was still trying to access an index out of the array. The difference to your example you linked above, is that they didn't used `EnvironmentObject` to access the array. The stored the array directly in the `@State`.

I came up with a little different approach, by declaring Item as `ObservedObject` and then simply pass it to the subview where you can use their values as Binding, without any function.

I changed Item to..

```
class Item: ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()
    var isOn: Bool
    
    init(id: UUID, isOn: Bool)
    {
        self.id = id
        self.isOn = isOn
    }
}
```

Change the ContentView to this..

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(model.items, id:\.id) {item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item)) {
                        Toggler(item: item)
                    }
                }.onDelete(perform: delete)
            }
        }
    }
```

I outsourced the Toggle to a different view, where we pass the ObservedObject to, same for the DetailView.

```
struct Toggler: View {
    @ObservedObject var item : Item
    
    var body : some View
    {
        Toggle(isOn: $item.isOn)
        {Text("Toggle-Text")}
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $item.isOn) {
            Text("Toggle-Text")
        }
    }
}
```

They both take an `Item` as ObservedObject and use it as Binding for the `Toggle`.