# SwiftUI: onDelete doesn't update UI correctly

Tags: swiftui

When I delete an element of an array using `onDelete()`, it removes the correct item in the data but removes the last item on the UI. I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62909982/13048225) but I am already using what it recommends. Any advice?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    
    var body: some View {
        Form{
            ForEach(items.indices, id:\.self){ itemIndex in
                
                let item = self.items[itemIndex]
                
                EditorView(container: self.$items, index: itemIndex, text: item)
                
            }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in

                self.items.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)

            })
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the EditorView struct:

```
struct EditorView : View {
    var container: Binding<[String]>
    var index: Int

    @State var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Type response here", text: self.$text, onCommit: {
            self.container.wrappedValue[self.index] = self.text
            
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ForEach` is looping over the `indices` of your array, so that is what `SwiftUI` is using to identify them.  When you delete an item, you have one fewer index for the array, so SwiftUI interprets that as the last one has been deleted.

To do this correctly, you should be looping over a list of `Identifiable` items that have a unique `id`.  Here I've created a `struct` called `MyItem` which holds the original `String` and a uniquely generated `id`.  I use `.map(MyItem.init)` to convert the items into a `[MyItem]`.

Also, your code needs the index in the loop, so loop over `Array(items.enumerated())` which will give you an array of `(offset, element)` tuples.  Then tell SwiftUI to use `\.element.id` as the `id`.

Note that `EditorView` now takes an Array of `MyItem`.

With these changes, SwiftUI will be able to identify the item you have deleted from the list and update the UI correctly.

```
struct MyItem: Identifiable {
    var name: String
    let id = UUID()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = ["One", "Two", "Three"].map(MyItem.init)
    
    var body: some View {
        Form{
            ForEach(Array(items.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, item in
                
                EditorView(container: self.$items, index: index, text: item.name)
                
            }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                
                self.items.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
            })
        }
    }
}

struct EditorView : View {
    var container: Binding<[MyItem]>
    var index: Int
    
    @State var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Type response here", text: self.$text, onCommit: {
            self.container.wrappedValue[self.index].name = self.text
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. Also, if you have any recommendations on on resources to understand Identifiable it would appreciated.

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/working-with-identifiable-items-in-swiftui

Comment: As you'll see in the tutorial, `Identifiable` works nicely because you can iterate over just the list, but in your case you also wanted the index, so we didn't really use the `Identifiable` protocol in that case because we explicitly specified the id in the `ForEach`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advice. I spent a couple hours trying out different things with `Identifiable` & think I am getting a good grasp on it.